# how to deploy / deployment django projects / application with aptana to webserver apache wsgi

Tags: django, aptana, pydev, wsgi

I would like to deplay a django application/project, which i have created within Aptana. It is a simple hello world. I can run the application locally and everything works fine, but how to deploy it to a webserver. The **deploy** button is grey and not working in the **PyDev Perspective**.
If i switch to perspective "Web Perspective" i can download(check out from a specific path with password) django applications from a webserver, edit files, and upload again. I would like to use the functionality from the **web perspective** in my **pydev perspective** where i write my django code.

But when i create my own django project, the button **deploy** is grey.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This is now my solution to deploy django 1.3 with aptana to Apache Server:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHiME.jpg

- Start Aptana, select PyDev Perspective (right corner) and just create a simple Django Project
- Create a views.py ane a method index()

> ```
> def index(request):
> return HttpResponse("Hello world")
> ```

- Edit your urls.py so that django can find the method index()
- Run Sync DB (rightclick your project in PyDev Package Explorer, at bottom click Django, and  click Sync DB). I am using here a local sqlite3 db
- if everything work,s you will see within Aptana Console: Finished "/home/xy/workspace/test1/test1/manage.py syncdb" execution.
- Now Run local your django app: rightclick your project on left side of aptana (PyDev Package Explorer) somewhere in the middle you can see RUN AS: 1 PyDev:Django
- Now open your browser: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/index` or `http://127.0.0.1:8000`
- U see now your "Hello World"

If this worked, now lets deploy to apache:

- switch to Web Perspective (right corner of Aptana)
- switch to App Explorer (left side of Aptana) IMPORTANT!!!!!
- there is a little dropdown menu: select there your application (e.g. test1), BUT do not select any of the packages or modules inside of your project!!
- you will see now your app and nothing is selected/clicked=> you see also a little box above!
- click it and Run Web Deployment Wizard!!! if anything in your package is selected, you will not see "Run Web Deployment Wizard".... (strange)
- Select SFTP Protocol; Fill out form
- **Remote Path:** before you can select the directory you want to have your app uploaded, you should create it on the server
- After you have selected the directory where you want to have your app deployed to server (ubuntu) you can again click on the little box and select **deploy app**
- Now you get a new window **SYNCHRONIZE**
- Your data/app have been now uploaded to server in the chosen directory
- I use wsgi so i have to edit 2 files
- the first one is a file called **test1.wsgi** in the wsgi directory

> import os
>
> import sys
>
> path = "/home/username/"
>
> if path not in sys.path:
>           sys.path.append(path)
>
> path = "/home/username/somedirectory/test1/test1/"
>
> if path not in sys.path:
>           sys.path.append(path)
>
> os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'
>
> import django.core.handlers.wsgi application =
>   django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()

- now go as sudo -s to cd /etc/apache2/conf.d/
- create a file **test1**
- write

> WSGIScriptAlias /rofltest /home/username/wsgi/test1.wsgi

- /rofltest means www.youraddress.org/rofltest will be the url
- /home/username/wsgi/test1.wsgi means where to look for a file which will tell where to look for your django app on the server
- restart apache (/etc/init.d/apache2 restart)  and browse to www.youraddress.org//rofltest/index
- You see Hello World or an error because you have to adjust the paths.
- Start with settings.py and edit ROOT_URLCONF = 'test1.urls' maybe just to 'urls'
- now it works :)

Try it, if it fails, write a comment and maybe i read it and help. If this helped, upvote it.

Answer (score 1):

It doesnt work for me. Even when I extra care about not selecting the project in the App Explorer, the small "publish" icon is enabled, but the dropdown beside it is empty and nothing happens when I click it.

Actually there is a known bug when the Project root is a source folder, see https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-2543

Comment: Yeah, i read about that bug. Took me some time. But i just tested it. For me it stil works. I get the RUN WIZARD thing: http://i.imgur.com/FH0E2.jpg. Try restart aptana and switching between pydev and web view.